# Opencart feed - take only products with price over 80

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-module

I would like that Opencart google base feed module take only products with price over 80. That way the opencart owners could only promote the products that are higher values and margins

How could I do it? I think this question could be beneficial for more opencart users.

Appreciate any the help :)

```
<?php 
class ControllerFeedGoogleBase extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        if ($this->config->get('google_base_status')) { 
            $output  = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';
            // $output .= '<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">';
            $output .= '<SHOP>';
            //$output .= '<title>' . $this->config->get('config_name') . '</title>'; 
            //$output .= '<description>' . $this->config->get('config_meta_description') . '</description>';
            //$output .= '<link>' . HTTP_SERVER . '</link>';

            $this->load->model('catalog/category');

            $this->load->model('catalog/product');

            $this->load->model('tool/image');

            $products = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts();

            foreach ($products as $product) {
                if ($product['description']) {
                    $output .= '<SHOPITEM>';
                    $output .= '<ITEM_ID>' . $product['product_id'] . '</ITEM_ID>';
                    $output .= '<PRODUCTNAME>' . $product['name'] . '</PRODUCTNAME>>';
                    $output .= '<PRODUCT>' . $product['name'] . '</PRODUCT>';
                    $output .= '<DESCRIPTION>' . '</DESCRIPTION>';
                    $output .= '<URL>' . $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product['product_id']) . '</URL>';
                    // $output .= '<description>' . $product['description'] . '</description>';
                    // $output .= '<g:brand>' . html_entity_decode($product['manufacturer'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '</g:brand>';
                    //$output .= '<g:condition>new</g:condition>';

                    if ($product['image']) {
                        $output .= '<IMGURL>' . $this->model_tool_image->resize($product['image'], 500, 500) . '</IMGURL>';
                    } else {
                        $output .= '<IMGURL>' . $this->model_tool_image->resize('no_image.jpg', 500, 500) . '</IMGURL>';
                    }

                    $output .= '<IMGURL_ALTERNATIVE>' . '</IMGURL_ALTERNATIVE>';
                    $output .= '<VIDEO_URL>' . '</VIDEO_URL>';



                    $supported_currencies = array('USD', 'EUR', 'GBP');

                    if (in_array($this->currency->getCode(), $supported_currencies)) {
                        $currency = $this->currency->getCode();
                    } else {
                        $currency = ($this->config->get('google_base_status')) ? $this->config->get('google_base_status') : 'USD';
                    }

                    if ((float)$product['special']) {
                        $output .= '<PRICE_VAT>' .  $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product['special'], $product['tax_class_id']), $currency, false, false) . '</PRICE_VAT>';
                    } else {
                        $output .= '<PRICE_VAT>' . $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product['price'], $product['tax_class_id']), $currency, false, false) . '</PRICE_VAT>';
                    }

                    $output .= '<HEUREKA_CPC>0.01' . '</HEUREKA_CPC>';
                    $output .= '<MANUFACTURER>' . html_entity_decode($product['manufacturer'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '</MANUFACTURER>';

                    $categories = $this->model_catalog_product->getCategories($product['product_id']);

                    foreach ($categories as $category) {
                        $path = $this->getPath($category['category_id']);

                        if ($path) {
                            $string = '';

                            foreach (explode('_', $path) as $path_id) {
                                $category_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($path_id);

                                if ($category_info) {
                                    if (!$string) {
                                        $string = $category_info['name'];
                                    } else {
                                        $string .= ' | ' . $category_info['name'];
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            $output .= '<CATEGORYTEXT>Hobby | Rybárčenie | ' . $string . '</CATEGORYTEXT>';
                        }
                    }

                    $output .= '<EAN>' . $product['ean'] . '</EAN>'; 
                    $output .= '<PRODUCTNO>' . $product['model'] . '</PRODUCTNO>';
                    $output .= '<DELIVERY_DATE>0</DELIVERY_DATE>
                                <DELIVERY>
                                    <DELIVERY_ID>UPS</DELIVERY_ID>';
                                    if ((float)$product['special']) {
                                        if($product['special']<65){
                                            $output .= '<DELIVERY_PRICE>3</DELIVERY_PRICE>' . '<DELIVERY_PRICE_COD>3</DELIVERY_PRICE_COD>';
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            $output .= '<DELIVERY_PRICE>0</DELIVERY_PRICE>' . '<DELIVERY_PRICE_COD>0</DELIVERY_PRICE_COD>';
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        if($product['price']<65){
                                            $output .= '<DELIVERY_PRICE>3</DELIVERY_PRICE>' . '<DELIVERY_PRICE_COD>3</DELIVERY_PRICE_COD>';
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            $output .= '<DELIVERY_PRICE>0</DELIVERY_PRICE>' . '<DELIVERY_PRICE_COD>0</DELIVERY_PRICE_COD>';
                                        }
                                    }
                                    $output .= '</DELIVERY>';

                    // $output .= '<g:quantity>' . $product['quantity'] . '</g:quantity>';
                     //$output .= '<g:upc>' . $product['ean'] . '</g:upc>'; 
                    // $output .= '<g:weight>' . $this->weight->format($product['weight'], $product['weight_class_id']) . '</g:weight>';
                    // $output .= '<g:availability>' . ($product['quantity'] ? 'in stock' : 'out of stock') . '</g:availability>';
                    $output .= '</SHOPITEM>';
                }
            }

            $output .= '</SHOP>'; 
            // $output .= '</rss>';     

            //$this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/rss+xml');
            $this->response->setOutput($output);
        }
    }

    protected function getPath($parent_id, $current_path = '') {
        $category_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($parent_id);

        if ($category_info) {
            if (!$current_path) {
                $new_path = $category_info['category_id'];
            } else {
                $new_path = $category_info['category_id'] . '_' . $current_path;
            }   

            $path = $this->getPath($category_info['parent_id'], $new_path);

            if ($path) {
                return $path;
            } else {
                return $new_path;
            }
        }
    }       
}
?>
```

Comment: in your query? ... WHERE priceColumn > minPriceValue(i.e. 80)

Comment: i am not quite sure how you mean it, could you please specify. The code above exports the XML for it

Comment: I assume you're getting products from a database, just limit the query to only include products with a price above or equal to 80

Comment: i think the code should contain something like if($product['price']<80){ ...but i am not quite sure, since i am not a developer.

Comment: you are getting all the products after calling $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts(); . So, you need to look into this method of catalog/product model . If possible then update your question with that method .

Comment: As I am aware of how opencart works you should not touch that part, because it would mess up the site....the only section needs to be modified is the one i have posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so since you can't edit the query itself.. this is one way to handle it..

```
....
foreach ($products as $product) {
    //Calculate the product's price, including tax.
    $priceCalc = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product['price'], $product['tax_class_id']), $currency, false, false);

    //Check if the price, (in the current currency), is higher or equal to 80.
    if ($product['description'] && $priceCalc >= 80) {
      //continue if true..
      $output .= '<SHOPITEM>';
      $output .= '<ITEM_ID>' . $product['product_id'] . '</ITEM_ID>';
....
```